# A script to copy files from folders with a specific file and folder names

Tags: regex, batch-file, xcopy

First, I should mention that have a windows machine.

Now, I want to copy files that have `until` as some part of their file names.

I have a folder named `my data`. I have several folders in it where they have four digits in the end of their names, such as `my_folder_0000`. I would like to find these folders, and copy the file with `until` being some part of their file names into another folder.

To clarify, please see the following example to better understand the structure:

```
my data/
   |-- /my_folder_0000/my_file_until_2010.csv
   |-- /his_folder_0001/his_file_until_2011.csv
   |-- /test
   |-- /documents
```

In the above example, I would like to go through the first two folders, copy the files into my folder on desktop.

I would like to have a script which works for windows. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at robocopy? (It's included with Windows.)

Comment: I have windows 7 and I do not find it on my machine. Maybe it was added to the newer versions?

Comment: That's odd. It's included in all Windows 7 versions. If you open a command prompt and just run robocopy - it should be in the path - you get a file not found? It's in windows\system32\robocopy.exe.

Comment: Found it! Thanks. But how can I use it to have a script which finds files and folders using the pattern mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea how to do it:

```
@echo off& setlocal
for /d %%d in ("%~1\*.*") do set dir=%%d& call :next_dir %2
exit /b

:next_dir
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%dir:~-4%") do exit /b
copy /y "%dir%\*until*.*" %1 | find "until"
```

At command line 1st arg is source directory (perhaps "\my data" in your case) and 2nd argument is destination directory for the copied files.

Existing/duplicate-named files are overwritten in destination without prompting.  Filenames are displayed as they are copied.

Comment: It did what I was looking for. Thank you! Do you have any tutorial/reference to recommend so I can learn more on this subject?

Comment: Sorry no single reference -- perhaps someone else can suggest a great book or two on the subject. I've slowly learned .bat scripting starting from the DOS days decades ago.  Obviously stackoverflow.com is a wonderful source for ingenious ways to _apply_ commands.  Of course study the help Microsoft gives via:    `call /?`   `set  /?`    `for /?`   etc     and experiment.